# Java How do I turn Callback to Promise?

Tags: java, promise, callback

## Java How do I turn Callback to Promise?

### Scenes

Previously, Java used a callback function to wait for the specified resource to load and then execute the callback. Now, if you want to change to Promise style, is there any good way?

E.g

```java
Void watch(Predicate<String> f, Consumer<Stat> callback)
```

Convert into

```java
Future<Stat> watch(Predicate<String> f)
```

By the way, I used to be asynchronous in Promise in JavaScript, but I am not familiar with it in Java. . .
Here is the code that wraps `setTimeout` as a Promise

```js
Var wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
```

So, is there any good solution?

---

I know that there are `CompletedFuture` and `CompletableFuture` in Java, but I don't know how to create a `CompletableFuture` object and use the bound callback function in the constructor.

For example, my class can indeed convert the following code into a currying function.

```java
Default void watch(String path, Consumer<Stat> callback) {
    Watch(map -> map.get(ListUtil.ListDiffState.right).stream()
            .filter(stat -> Objects.equals(stat.getPath(), path))
            .findFirst(), callback);
}
```

After conversion

```java
Default Consumer<Consumer<Stat>> watch(String path) {
    Return callback -> watch(path, callback);
}
```

However, my generation can't convert it to `CompletedFuture` asynchronous style (cannot get the callback function of `CompletedFuture` binding), ask for advice!

---

The code I am calling now is as follows

```java
watch("/test/test.xml", stat -> {
     Log.info("Result file has been created: {}", stat)
})
```

The idealized call should be

```java
watch("/test/test.xml")
     .thenAccept(stat -> {
         Log.info("Result file has been created: {}", stat)
     })
```

Comment: What are you trying to load?  Can you show some code?

Comment: I modified the problem and added the difference in the call at the end.

Comment: Is there any good way?（ｖ＾＿＾）ｖ